# Laravel eloquent relationship - multiple whereHas and whereIn for different filter options

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have multiple many-to-many relationships and i want to filter through them.
The models are:

- State
- District

I attached an screenshot:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJPwp.png)

States are Alabama and Arizona, Districts are Autaga, Baldwin and Apache

When i check Alabama and Arizona the query works and i get the requested items.
Now i only want items from Arizona and Autaga - but the query just returns items from Autaga.

```
$query->when($states, function ($query) use ($districts, $states) {
    $query->whereHas('states', function($query) use($states) {
        $query->whereIn('name', $states);
    });
});
$query->when($districts, function ($query) use ($districts, $states) {
    $query->where(function ($subQuery) use ($states, $districts) {
        $subQuery->whereHas('states', function($query) use($states) {
            $query->whereIn('name', $states);
        });
        $subQuery->whereHas('districts', function($query) use($districts) {
            $query->whereIn('name', $districts);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you use and logic, the result must satisfy both conditions. So use orWhere, try:

```
$query->when($districts || $states, function ($query) use ($districts, $states) {
    $query->whereHas('states', function($query) use($states) {
        $query->whereIn('name', (array) $states);
    });

    $query->orWhere( function($query) use($districts){
        $query->whereHas('districts', function($query) use($districts) {
            $query->whereIn('name', (array) $districts);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The code works quite well - theres only one problem left. When the request is $states only, the query should return all items for that specific state. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution of your query :

```html
if (!empty($districts)) {
    $query->whereHas('states', function($query) use($states) {
        $query->whereIn('name', $states);
    })
    ->whereHas('districts', function($query) use($districts) {
        $query->whereIn('name', $districts);
    });
} else {
    $query->whereHas('states', function($query) use($states) {
        $query->whereIn('name', $states);
    });
}
```

Hope this will help you.